# How to add shadow effects on icons like font-awesome

Tags: css

I want to add a shadow on hover effect in my icon:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to add a shadow effect using css?
The icon is from font-awesome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) to learn how to use `text-shadow`.

Syntax is `offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color`:

```css
.icon-red {
  color: #c00000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<i class="fas fa-3x fa-heart icon-red"></i>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `text-shadow` like:

```css
shadow:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content:"\f0c9";
    padding:0 5px 0 15px;   
    font-size: 300px;
    text-shadow: 10px 10px 10px blue;
}
```

```html
<shadow></shadow>
```